# Reading from xml config in maven using cmd

Tags: maven, command-line, spring-integration, config

This is my first time using maven, so this is probably a silly question. Originally I was using just NetBeans, and my program was reading a spring-integration xml config file in the main method. Now, I'm trying to make the xml file a command line argument (windows), in case someone wants to pass in a different config file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FileSystemXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);

}
```

Comment: Hi Artem, I did that and got: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: @arsenal11 You have to start your Java program with the xml config file as parameter.

Comment: Well, it isn't going to work if you don't give it any argument. In your case it must be a path to the XML file in your Windows.

Comment: My cmd is currently only recognizing the mvn command when I'm in the apache-maven-3.5.0\bin directory, so I'm not sure how to run my project which is in a different folder. I was just pressing run in netbeans earlier. Sorry I'm very new to all this!